# adding image file to change background image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So hi hello there first of all...
I ran into a little **problem** and am  having a tough time trying to figure it out.

So basically what i am trying to do is be able for the user to click on a button that will allow them to select an image and after that it will grab the url of that image locally and change the background image of a div.

Now i am using the window variable but thinking about trying this out without it and just having the event listener do its thing. But havent tested that out kinda of feel like that wont work.. just a thought. but anyways, t**his works for when i only have one event listener target the button but if i do 2 then it gives me a security warning telling me that it may not load data from the blob**... any idea of how to proceed with the vision?

**Below is the html code:**

```
<h3 class="m-heading">Project</h3>
<div class="projectIMG">
    <input type="file" id="projectImgBtn">
</div>
```

**Below is the javscript**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(){
        if(this.files && this.files[0]){
            const background = document.querySelector('.insertImage');
            console.log(background)
            // console.log(background.style.backgroundImage)
            background.style.backgroundImage = `url('${URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])}')`
            background.onload = imageLoaded;
        }
    })
    projectImg.addEventListener('change', function(){
        if(this.files && this.files[0]){
            const background = document.querySelector('.projectIMG')
            console.log(background)
            background.style.backgroundImage = `url('${URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])})`
            background.onload = imageLoaded
        }
    })
})
```

This is the full error
[image: this would be the error]

Comment: Got any backend for this? I believe the image file has to reside somewhere statically, not in the browser's memory. Preferably, the file should be uploaded and stored on the server, preferably in /static dir of your application. This way, you could reference it in browser directly via simple GET.

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski, a `blob` of an image can be loaded from an image stored locally on the user's computer and then used.

Comment: @imvain2 Within an <img> element, it seems you are right, agreed. But as a `background` CSS property?

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski why not? `createObjectURL` creates a URL for it so it can be used as the background image.

Comment: But I imagine that's gonna be accessed via file:// protocol, not http.

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski would you say it is easier to create my current project within a database for it to be easier? if so what would you recommend? this is a little but like a notes app, would you say react would be best or vue with mongo?

Comment: @imvain2 i did create a  **createObjectUrl** which grabs the url that i receives from url it got from the button and creates a link that will make it readable when i add it to the style tag

Comment: @de_gentleman, I was referring to Marek who wasn't sure it can be done, so I said `createObjectUrl` was how to do it.

Comment: @de_gentleman not really a database; a **server** capable of serving static files and some endpoint for uploading them

Comment: @MarekPiotrowski mmm if i were to use the xamp server will that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

yout need to get the base64 for put it in the background.

Try this:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = e => variable = e.target.result;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```